# Web scraping using requests-html - How does one collect a simple number from a website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

I am trying to collect a data point from an electricity data website:
[electricityMap | Live CO₂ emissions of electricity consumption](https://app.electricitymap.org/zone/DK-DK2.)

So far I have written this code:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession              #import libraries

s = HTMLSession()

url = 'https://app.electricitymap.org/zone/DK-DK2'

r = s.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.74 Safari/537.36'})

webpageTitle = (r.html.find('title', first=True).text)
print(webpageTitle)
```

I am able to get VS Code to print out the title of the website but I am only interested in the amount of renewable energy in the given moment. This is displayed as the "renewable" dial in the top left on the website.

I have inspected the website and found the value I am trying to collect: [Screenshot of Chrome DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IjRn.png).

What do i need to write to be able to print this value in Python?

Comment: That web site is built entirely through Javascript.  None of that text is present in the HTML as downloaded (have you looked at it?).  You would need to use Selenium to run a real Chrome browser in order to have the Javascript executed.  Before doing to all that trouble, you should check to see if this web site has an API where you can fetch the number directly.   This is the kind of site that might have such a thing.

Comment: Thanks Tim. It is my first time working with HTML/Javascript. Definitely a rookie mistake to mix up the two. Hvae applied for a key to access API. Will give that a try as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ Tim Roberts has stated that the web site is built entirely through Javascrip. I tested both `requests_html` and `selenium`. requests_html gives empty outupt meaning can't render JavaScript but selenium produce the perfect output.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession    #import libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
         
s = HTMLSession()

url = 'https://app.electricitymap.org/zone/DK-DK2'

r = s.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.74 Safari/537.36'})


soup=bs(r.text,'html.parser')
renewable=[x.get_text() for x in soup.select('g[class="circular-gauge"] text')]
print(renewable)
```

Output:

[]

```
#Selenium: You have nothing to install just  you can run the code


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

url = 'https://app.electricitymap.org/zone/DK-DK2'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)


soup=bs(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
renewable=[x.get_text() for x in soup.select('g[class="circular-gauge"] text')][1]
print(renewable)
```

Output:

```
69%
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @F.hoque from the programming rookie! This was exactly what I was looking for.